# X server doesn't continue after wakeup from suspension

Tags: xorg, nvidia, gentoo, suspend, x-server

I have Gentoo system with [OpenRC](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/OpenRC) init, `5.4.28-gentoo` kernel and `440.64` Nvidia drivers (GTX 1060).

Everything configured according to [this guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVIDIA/nvidia-drivers).

When I suspend the system with **Gnome suspend button** and then wake it up, the monitor also wakes up but remains black. I can't switch to any TTY, but system is working and I can connect to SSH server.

The only way how I can get the screen back is by restarting xdm:

```
rc-service xdm restart
```

But I lose my session with this.

This problem didn't occur with the open-source nouveau driver.

I'm currently workarounding it with this script. (pm-suspend works fine)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xdg-screensaver lock
sleep 0.5
sudo pm-suspend
```

Is there any kernel option or system configuration that can cause this or that can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar problem in the [thread](https://forum.artixlinux.org/index.php/topic,1639.msg11220.html) of another forum.

I noticed there is a completely missing `/lib64/elogind/system-sleep/nvidia` file in my system. So I created this file with the following content and now everything works properly.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    pre)
        /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh "suspend"
        ;;

    post)
        (/usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh "resume";)&
        ;;
esac
```